# SMS icon not align to left_of switch in Android

Tags: android

[image]

This is the code I'm using a linearlayout and Relative inside this. I don't want to use margin_left because it is constant I want to adjust the sms button just left of switch shown.

I tried leftof but there is exception in XML file the only option I got is to use margin from left, that is fixed.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/call"
            android:id="@+id/caller_switch_tv" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/caller_switch_tv"
    android:id="@+id/caller_switch" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sms"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/caller_switch"
            android:id="@+id/sms_sender_swich_tv"

            />
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sms_sender_swich_tv"
            android:id="@+id/sms_switch" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/caller_switch_tv"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Call"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sms_sender_swich_tv"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sms_sender_swich_tv"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="SMS"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will fall apart on any other device you try it on, trust me, I've been there. You should use linear layouts with weights in order to get the desired outcome. Split the screen using 3 horizontal lin. layouts in a vertical one, and top and bottom horizontal split in half to make it look like your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caller_switch_tv"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/call" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/caller_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/caller_switch_tv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/caller_switch_tv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sms_sender_swich_tv"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sms_switch"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sms_switch"
            android:background="@drawable/sms"   
            />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/sms_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```